# Increment a file to be looked up in excel

Tags: excel, file, numbers, formula, increment

If I have a number of files representing weeks of a business named for example Week 1, Week 2, Week 3 etc. where each new week looks at data from the previous week. I have written this formula

```
='C:\Users\David\Documents\Excel\[Week 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E5
```

In the file for Week 3.

Is there a way to increase the week number each week without manually having to change each cell containing this formula? I have tried by using 1 cell to represent the week number, in this case "3" (in cell 1A) and then using =1A-1 to give the value 2 (in cell A2) but then was unable to use this in any way to replace the file extension

Basically what i want using the values given above would be to change

```
='C:\Users\David\Documents\Excel\[Week 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E5
```

into

```
='C:\Users\David\Documents\Excel\[Week (CELL A2).xlsx]Sheet1'!$E5
```

so each week cell A2 would be changed to the previous week number by subtracting 1 from the current week number in cell A1 and using this to update all formulas containing (CELL A2)

Thank you if you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\Users\David\Documents\Excel\[Week "&A2&".xlsx]Sheet1'!$E5")
```